# How to php lint only present and modified files in gitlab?

Tags: php, git, gitlab

I have the following command in my gitlab-ci.yml which runs 'php -l' on every php file that was changed the the commit:

```
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - for file in $(git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~1 | egrep "\.php$"); do php -l $file; done
```

The problem I have, is if a php file is removed, it tries to lint that too, and fails because the file doesn't exists.

How can I get it to only check changed PHP files that are present?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `git diff --name-status` option. this command returns like this:

```
A       a.php # added file
D       b.php # deleted file
M       c.php # modified file
```

Please see more details.
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff---name-status

The following command is using this option and check syntax except removed files:

```
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - for file in $(git diff --name-status HEAD~1 HEAD | egrep "^[ACMR].*\.php$" | cut -c 3-); do php -l $file; done
```

`git diff --name-status HEAD HEAD~1` returns reversed file status, so I did `git diff --name-status HEAD~1 HEAD`.

Comment: This is really good, but I'm getting an issue with RENAMED files (ie: files that have changed their location).

Comment: First thank you @kuromoka for this great one-liner! :)
@David for the renaming I decided to add a quick check for file existence like this: `for file in $(git diff --name-status HEAD~1 HEAD | egrep "^[ACMR].*\.php$" | cut -c 3-); do [ -f $file ] && php -l $file; done`